# Highlight diferences in a dashtable - python

Tags: python, frontend, plotly-dash

I am new to dash and trying to style my dashtable so that every cell with a different value from the cell in the same column in the first row gets highlighted.

I tried something like this

```
import dash
import dash_table
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],
                   'B': [4, 5, 6],
                   'C': [7, 7, 7]})

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns],
    style_data_conditional=[
        {
            'if': {
                'filter_query': '{{{column}}}[{row}] != {{{column}}}[0]'.format(column=column, row=row),
            },
            'backgroundColor': 'yellow',
            'color': 'white',
        } for column in df.columns for row in range(1,len(df))
    ]
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

... but I keep getting the same Error that I dont really understand:
DataTable filtering syntax is invalid for query: {A}[1] != {A}[0]

Can someone help me figure it out? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly why the error happens, it seems you cannot specify `{column}[rowindex]`..

Anyway, the following conditional should work :

```py
    style_data_conditional=[{
        'if': {
            'column_id': f'{column}',
            'filter_query': f'{{{column}}} != {df[column][0]}',
        },
        'backgroundColor': 'yellow',
        'color': 'white',
    } for column in df.columns ]
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to work. What about when both the data and the style data conditional are return values of a callback function ? How do I specify style data conditional to work with a dynamic dataframe ? Sorry I am very new to dash and a bit confused.

Comment: You could use a callback that updates the whole dataTable (with new data and style conditionals), in which case you need to wrap it inside a div (in the layout) in order for the callback output to target the children property of that div. Or a callback with 2 outputs, one for the data and the other for the style conditionals. Feel free to ask another (more specific) question if you struggle with callbacks.

Comment: Hey @EricLavault, thanks a lot, 
[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75742904/dynamic-dataframe-and-conditional-styling-in-dash-callbacks